# Scipy error using optimization module. Failure converting array to fortran

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

Trying to use scipy's optimize module to find the minimum of a function using slsqp and I'm running into some issues. The actual code calling the function is shown below:

```
def minimizeWebEnergyLost(x, parameters):
    """values = [theta, velocity]"""
    firstTerm = lambda values: (x * values[1]**2 / 2.0)
    sqrtTerm = lambda values: np.sqrt((parameters.gravity**2 * x**2) / (4 * values[1]**4 * np.cos(values[0])**4) + 1)
    secondTerm = lambda values: (values[1]**4 * np.cos(values[0])**2) / parameters.gravity
    arcsinhTerm = lambda values: np.arcsinh((parameters.gravity * x) / (2 * values[1]**2 * np.cos(values[0])**2))
    costFunction = lambda values: firstTerm(values)*sqrtTerm(values)+secondTerm(values)*arcsinhTerm(values)
    bounds = ((-math.pi/2,math.pi/2),(0,parameters.maxSlingSpeed))
    minimum = minimize(costFunction, (pi/4, 20), method="SLSQP", bounds=bounds)
    return minimum
```

For some reason the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
_slsqp.error: failed in converting 8th argument `g' of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array
```

Not quite sure what's going on hre, but I can put up  any more code that might be useful if it helps.

Comment: Do you get the same error with the `scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp` version instead?

Comment: Exactly the same error when I use that version.

Comment: Does a really simple example work for you? E.g. `def costFunction(x): retun x[0]**2 + x[1]**2`, etc.  Also, what version of scipy are you using?

Comment: Yea, a simple function seems to work fine. Using 0.12.0.

Comment: Can you create a minimal self-contained example that generates the error and add the code to the question?

Comment: were you able to find any solution. thanks

Comment: @Akash The best that I can figure out is that is has something to do with SLSQP having trouble dealing with instability

Answer (score 0):

This cryptic error occurs when the user specified objective function does not returning a scalar. A clear error message is now returned in a patch by [b-carter](https://github.com/b-carter),

```
"Objective function must return a scalar"
```

and the documentation is updated, see [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5433) thread for discussion.