# Failed in converting 8th argument `g' of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array for Scipy.Optimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to optimize the following equation in python:

argmax(Z) L=Z^TA+rZ^TB s.t. Z^TB=0 (excuse me for not being able to post images since this account isn't used that often, but ^T means transpose)

where r is a scalar and Z, A, and B are column vectors. How should I put this in scipy.optimize.minimize? But I keep getting an error that I don't recognize.

Currently my code is

```
def func(x, sign = 1.0):
    """ Objective function """
    sums = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sums = sums - x[i] * a[i] - rm * x[i] * b[i]
    return sums
def func_deriv(x, sign = 1.0):
    """ Derivative of objective function """
    return - a[i] - rm * b[i]
def c1(x):
    sums = 0
    print x
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sums = sums + x[i] * b[i]
    return sums
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
        'fun' : c1,})
res = minimize(func, np.zeros(len(a)), jac=func_deriv, constraints=cons, method='SLSQP')
```

Right now, the following error occurs at the `constraints=cons` part:

`error: failed in converting 8th argument`g' of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array`

I saw on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733897/scipy-fmin-slsqp-error-failed-in-converting-8th-argument-g-of-slsqp-slsqp-to) that this error means that the returned object needs to be a scalar. But function `c1` does return a scalar, so I'm confused now. Are there any other sources of error?

Comment: Your function `func_deriv` uses `i`, but `i` is not defined.  I think that should be simply `return -a - rm*b`.

Comment: Sry for the late response but thanks!